# Repairing my FFC connector - what to use?

Tags: raspberry-pi, ffc

I'm using a Pi Camera v2.1 and a 15-pin FFC

My 150mm, 15-pin Flat Flax Connector (on 1 side) has 1 pin slightly shortened (metal torn). My Raspberry Pi 3 is not working with it. What should I do:

1. Try to do a software fix
2. Get a £2 new flex cable
3. Fix the cable (How?)

Comment: Go for option 2, chances of a successful repair are slim...

Comment: If you want to attempt to fix the cable, post a picture of the parts and the damage, but yeah 2 L money is a fair bit of real money, but still not too bad for a specialized cable.

Comment: While technically a _repair question_, this is trivial enough that there's no need for a lengthy to-and-fro discussion which would be the main objection. The answer will likely be helpful to a lot of users in the future. I think it's a good question and not off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Before getting a replacement, you can try cutting the cable with scissors to so that all pins go to the edge:

[image]

(picture borrowed from [here](http://jestineyong.com/ribbon-cable-repair-tip/))

Putting the cable between two sheets of paper (and cutting the whole sandwich together) helps to restrain the cable as you cut it, limiting the damage from deformation. clear plastic sheets work too, with the advantage that you get to see the cable as you cut it.

Worst case, you further damage your already damaged cable.